# How can I guarantee that I will beat the Duck Hunt challenge (grants Mew spirit) in World of Light?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

*There are spoilers for the story mode of Super Smash Bros. Ultimate here, mainly regarding one of the challenges in World of Light and* ***the final boss.*** *You've been warned! Just in case, all spoiler-related text has been hidden in a spoiler block quote.*

I've reached a point in World of Light where I've beaten all the spirit battles (at least, I think I have) **except** for the final boss.

(***Spoiler below***)

> How can I guarantee that I will beat both Galeem and Dharkon *and* receive the Duck Hunt challenge **("Beat the final boss without being KOed")**, though? And does this imply that you need to lose absolutely no stocks in all 3 phases, or just the final phase (I've heard that you get your stocks revived after beating the first 2 phases)?

Continuing on with this, 
(***Spoiler below***)

> What happens if I don't meet the requirements for the challenge but still beat the boss? Will I have to restart WoL all over again just for this one singular challenge? Or, is there some kind of method that will 100% guarantee the completion of this challenge?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is no real way to guarantee you'll beat the challenge, but there is a way to guarantee you'll unlock it (explained below).

If you want to legitimately beat the challenge, these are the important parts to know about:

- (in case this is not obvious) you can use any character for the challenge. You do not need to use the Duck Hunt Duo at all.
- The challenge is not limited to only the boss fight. It applies for the entirety of the final level. This includes the platforming section at the very beginning. You are absolutely not allowed to die. At all.
- You can get the challenge on any difficulty, including Easy.
- You do not need to restart WoL if you fail the challenge. In fact, you can experience all 3 endings without restarting WoL.

Some tips to make it easier:

- You can attack Galeem and Dharkon during the platforming section. Hit them enough, and they'll leave.
- Equipping spirits of the same franchise gives them a boost in power. The higher the power, the more damage you deal, and the less you receive in return.
- **[This was accurate about a year ago and needs to be reconfirmed]** If you know how to handle Olimar, for some reason his aerials are both weapon and physical attacks. As a result, you can double your attack bonus via both the skill tree, and your spirits. If done properly, you can defeat Giga Bowser in as few as 3 shots.

---

If the challenge truly is too hard, you can still unlock it using a hammer.

[image: Screenshot of challenge menu with hammer]

Simply select the hammer (if you have one), and then select the challenge you want to unlock.

You can earn more hammers by unlocking a certain number of challenges (either legitimately, or using the hammer). Obviously, hammers are limited, so keep them for challenges you cannot beat yourself.

Comment: Certain support spirit abilities can be very useful as well.  Celebi automatically restores 5% damage every few seconds which can make endurance battles like this one much simpler.

Comment: Echoing Celebi. Autoheal is probably the best ability for clearing the last stage without dying. In particular, during the second part where you fight all the bosses, you can just wait in between the boss battles whilst autoheal heals all your HP (just keep an eye out for the fire attacks that punish you for idling). Very Easy is also a new mode introduced by DLC which can help further.